# Password checker doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as c:
    url = "https://www.roblox.com/newlogin"
    UserName = input("Your username is > ")
    PassWord = input("Your password is > ")
    c.get(url)
    login_data = dict(username = UserName, password = PassWord, next='/')
    r = c.post(url, data=login_data, headers={"Referer":"https://www.roblox.com/newlogin"})
if r.headers.status_code == 302:
    print("Successfully logged in")
else:
    print("Invalid username or password")
```

This is my code, it's supposed to check if the user name and password are correct, for some reason when I put the real password and the real username it still prints `("Invalid username or password")`, What do I do wrong?

Comment: Can you provide some info about `r` object? What is status code?

Comment: The site uses a XSRF token. It has to be retrieved and send back.

Comment: The status code is 302